# How to mock async method with jest in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I have below mentioned files

|_ utils.js
|_methods.js

I am doing unit testing for rest.js methods, file contents are

**methods.js**

```
import Express from 'express'
import { add_rec } from './utils'

export const create_rec = () => async (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
    const rec_body = req.body.rec

    return add_rec(rec_body)
        .then((ret) => res.status(201).send(ret))
        .catch((e) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: e.message })
        })
}
```

How can mock the **add_rec** async function so that I can unit-test my **create_rec**
function

I am trying to test create_rec below way but it is not allowing me to mock add_rec method

```
mport { getMockReq, getMockRes } from '@jest-mock/express'
import { add_rec } from './utils'
jest.mock('./utils')

describe('test create_rec method valid param', () => {
    it('test create_rec method', async () => {
        const req = getMockReq({
            body: {
                rec: {},
            },
        })
        const { res } = getMockRes<any>({
            status: jest.fn(),
            send: jest.fn(),
        })
        add_rec.mockResolved({}) // this line is giving error in fact it is not mocked i think
        await create_rec()(req, res)
        expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, except that you need to do some processing on the TS type of the mock method, you can use type assertion.

E.g.

`methods.ts`:

```
import Express from 'express';
import { add_rec } from './utils';

export const create_rec = () => async (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
  const rec_body = req.body.rec;

  return add_rec(rec_body)
    .then((ret) => res.status(201).send(ret))
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: e.message });
    });
};
```

`utils.ts`:

```
export async function add_rec(params): Promise<any> {
  console.log('real implementation');
}
```

`methods.test.ts`:

```
import Express from 'express';
import { create_rec } from './methods';
import { add_rec } from './utils';

jest.mock('./utils');

describe('68419899', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    (add_rec as jest.MockedFunction<any>).mockResolvedValueOnce({});
    const req = ({ body: { rec: {} } } as unknown) as Express.Request;
    const res = ({ status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() } as unknown) as Express.Response;
    await create_rec()(req, res);
    expect(add_rec).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(res.status).toBeCalledWith(201);
    expect(res.send).toBeCalledWith({});
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68419899/methods.test.ts (8.659 s)
  68419899
    ✓ should pass (5 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   81.82 |      100 |   66.67 |      75 |                   
 methods.ts |   88.89 |      100 |      80 |   83.33 | 10                
 utils.ts   |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.198 s
```